# lodash .groupBy. how to add your own keys for grouped output?

Tags: javascript, object, key, lodash

```
[{
    "car_brand": "audi",
    "model": {
      "model_1": "audi_tt"
    }

  },
  {
    "car_brand": "audi",
    "model": {
      "model_1": "audi_r8"
    }
  }
]
```

anyways convert to as be

```
[{
  "car_brand": "audi",
  "model": [{
      "model_1": "audi_tt"
    },
    {
      "model_1": "audi_r8"
    }
  ]
}]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can first use [`_.groupBy()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#groupBy) to group each object, and then [`_.map()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#map) each group in the object to an array of objects. Each mapped object uses the key from the grouped object as the `car_brand`, as well as uses a mapped version of the grouped value array as the `model` property:

```js
const arr = [{ "car_brand": "audi", "model": { "model_1": "audi_tt" } }, { "car_brand": "audi", "model": { "model_1": "audi_r8" } } ];

const group = _.flow(
  inp => _.groupBy(inp, 'car_brand'),
  gr => _.map(gr, (arr, card_brand) => ({
    card_brand,
    model: _.map(arr, 'model')
  }))
);

console.log(group(arr));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.15/lodash.min.js"></script>
```